# ArcSde Oracle Maximum number of grids per feature (8000)

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I have a problem with the import of data (lines) to ArcSde Oracle.

2011-07-14 12:10:04| 22.9| 0.0|ERROR |Error while executing stream insert operation for table 'CHEMN'.:SDE_ERROR_CODE(-51) Underlying DBMS error. SDE_EXT_ERROR(29875) SDE_ERROR_MSG1(ORA-29875: échec d'exécution de la routine ODCIINDEXINSERT
ORA-20092: Maximum number of grids per feature (8000) exceeded.
ORA-06512: à "SDE.ST_DOMAIN_METHODS", ligne 1982

Have you a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not saying which ArcSDE version you are using but the Max no of grids value is controlled by the SERVER_CONFIG system table. You can use the sdeconfig command to alter these values. FOr an example with ArcSDE 9.2 have a look at http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=2344&pid=2337&topicname=Troubleshooting_the_ArcSDE_service

Comment: I use ArcSde 10 with Oracle 11g.

Comment: Hmm.. ok. Maybe your grid size defined is too small. Have a look at this esri thread : http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/34736-ArcSDE-Oracle-Maximum-number-of-grids-per-feature-%288000%29-exceeded and also this paper on tuning grid sizes: http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc05/papers/pap1858.pdf

Comment: And how to change the grid size in ArcSde Oracle ? (SQL)

Comment: Using the sdelayer -o alter command, using the -g GRID, <gridsize> param. For more details check the online help: http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/support_files/datamgmt/sdelayer.htm